# Array initialisation with JSON data - lua

Tags: arrays, json, lua

I want to initialise my array value like JSON data ,When i try its not initialising as properly,Here my code

My JSON value

```
 [{"ShiftCode":"1","ShiftName":"BREAKFAST"},
 {"ShiftCode":"2","ShiftName":"LUNCH"}, 
 {"ShiftCode":"2","ShiftName":"LUNCH"},
 {"ShiftCode":"3","ShiftName":"DINNER"},
 {"ShiftCode":"3","ShiftName":"DINNER"}]
```

I tried like the following

```
 shiftArr={'[[[{"ShiftCode":"1","ShiftName":"BREAKFAST"},{"ShiftCode":"2","ShiftName":"LUNCH"},{"ShiftCode":"2","ShiftName":"LUNCH"},{"ShiftCode":"3","ShiftName":"DINNER"},{"ShiftCode":"3","ShiftName":"DINNER"}]]]'};
```

It not working,What change should i want to do further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to parse JSON data into a Lua table. If so, try this code:

```
J=[[
[{"ShiftCode":"1","ShiftName":"BREAKFAST"},
 {"ShiftCode":"2","ShiftName":"LUNCH"}, 
 {"ShiftCode":"2","ShiftName":"LUNCH"},
 {"ShiftCode":"3","ShiftName":"DINNER"},
 {"ShiftCode":"3","ShiftName":"DINNER"}] 
]]

L={}
n=0
for t in J:gmatch("%b{}") do
    n=n+1
    L[n]={}
    for k,v in t:gmatch('"(.-)":"(.-)"') do
        L[n][k]=v   
    end
end
```

Comment: @Fazil, try adding `print(n,k,v)` in the inner loop.

Comment: @Fazil works here! please be specific in your comments, "its not working" doesn't say what's wrong. If you run the code you will get a table of 5 subtables, each one having two keys, associated with the values shown in your JSON.