# How to convert string into a table in Lua

Tags: lua, lua-table

I am having a table data in string form. Sample is given below:

```
{"engName1":"HOLDER","validDurPeriod":3,"engName2":"INFORMATION","appStatus":2,"stayExpDate":"01/10/2012","engName3":"","appExpDate":"12/04/2010"}
```

How can I convert it into a proper table type variable so that I can access keys.I am new to lua and I am not aware if there is any existing method to do so.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22632596/array-initialisation-with-json-data-lua.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [plenty](http://lua-users.org/wiki/JsonModules) of JSON parsers available for Lua, for example [dkjson](http://dkolf.de/src/dkjson-lua.fsl/home):

```
local json = require ("dkjson")

local str = [[
{
  "numbers": [ 2, 3, -20.23e+2, -4 ],
  "currency": "\u20AC"
}
]]

local obj, pos, err = json.decode (str, 1, nil)
if err then
  print ("Error:", err)
else
  print ("currency", obj.currency)
  for i = 1,#obj.numbers do
    print (i, obj.numbers[i])
  end
end
```

Output:

```
currency    €
1   2
2   3
3   -2023
4   -4
```

Comment: is this applicable on mobile platforms also. Because I am working on Kony framework for J2ME devices using lua as language..and when I tried to put this file, it is not even letting me start my app..also i tried with different json parser, then it is unable to identify keyword "require"...

Comment: @Vikram I'm not sure about that, `require` is a built-in function http://www.lua.org/pil/8.1.html so generally it should be there..

Answer (score 1):

Try this code to start with

```
J=[[
{"engName1":"HOLDER","validDurPeriod":3,"engName2":"INFORMATION","appStatus":2,"stayExpDate":"01/10/2012","engName3":"","appExpDate":"12/04/2010"}
]]
J=J:gsub("}",",}")
L={}
for k,v in J:gmatch('"(.-)":(.-),') do
    L[k]=v   
    print(k,v)
end
```

You'll still need to convert some values to number and remove quotes.

Alternatively, you can let Lua do the hard work, if you trust the source string. Just replace the loop by this:

```
J=J:gsub('(".-"):(.-),','[%1]=%2,\n')
L=loadstring("return "..J)()
```

Comment: do I have to add those square brackets into string for this operation.?? Please ask if something is not clear from my side..

Comment: @Vikram Yes. The square brackets will tell lua that the item inside it is a key.

Comment: @Vikram, for the sample data you gave, you don't need to add square brackets around keys. I just wanted to make the code a little more robust, in case keys had spaces in them.

Comment: @lhf: I am trying with your second approach and it is crashing at "J=J:gsub('(".-"):(.-),','[%1]=%2,\n')". I have added brackets at both ends. Is this a generic code or only given sample specific, because my actual string is having a collection as a value of one of keys.

Comment: @Vikram, in the second code, I assume the definition of `J` as in the first one. Is that what you're talking about? What error message is shown in the crash?

Comment: yes..the only difference is one of key is having table again as value..eg: {"engName1":{"key1":"asdf","Key2","asdf"},"validDurPeriod":3}. like that..

Comment: do we have to make any change for this case??

Comment: @Vikram, ah, in that case you need a more powerful substitution and cannot be done with a single `gsub`.

Comment: cannot provide you with the crash logs. This is the worst part because this is limitation of Kony.

Comment: The last component of `J` is not terminated with `,`, so it will not be processed in the second solution.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, I meant the second solution to replace the loop. I've edited my answer.